# how we push a data to an array in laravel5?

Tags: angularjs, laravel

How we push data to the array in laravel5?

push a data to the array:-

**THERE IS SOME CODE THAT I HAVE SHARED AS BELOW:**

```
if(!empty($request))
{
    $request->all();
    $lan_user_location = $request[0];
    $lat_user_location = $request[1];

    $vehiclelocation = Vehicle::select('veh_last_location')->get()->toArray();
    $location = json_decode($vehiclelocation[849]['veh_last_location']);
    $rows[] = $location;

    foreach($rows as $key=>$value){
        $lan_vehicle=$rows[$key][$key]->long;
        $lat_vehicle=$rows[$key][$key]->lati;
    }

    $location = json_decode($vehiclelocation[851]['veh_last_location']);
    $distance = $this->nearesrtdistance(
                        $lat_user_location,
                        $lan_user_location,
                        $lat_vehicle, 
                        $lan_vehicle
                );

    if($distance<30)
    {
        $nearlatlong[] = $lat_vehicle;
        $nearlatlong[] = $lan_vehicle;

        $response = [
            'status'        => 'success', 
            'nearlatlong'   => $nearlatlong, 
            'statusCode'    => Response::HTTP_OK
        ];

        return response()->json(['response' => $response]);
}
```

Want push lat and long on the $nearlatlong array

Comment: I think that `$nearlatlong[] = $lat_vehicle;` should be inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$nearlatlong[] = array(
       'lat' => $lat_vehicle,
       'lan' => $lan_vehicle
 );
```

To Retrive Data from `$nearlatlong`

```
foreach($nearlatlong as $nearlatlong){
    $lat_vehicle = $nearlatlong->lat;
    $lan_vehicle = $nearlatlong->lan;
}
```

By this way you can store multiple lan & lat into a single array.

Answer (score -1):

You can push items into php arrays by using `array_push()` function. `array_push()` receives the array and all the items you want to add as arguments.

For example:

```
<?php
 $array1= array('Mathematics','Physics');
 array_push($array1,'Chemistry','Biology');
 print_r($array1);
?>
```